# S3 high-availability + reliability for backups

Tags: amazon-s3, backup, high-availability, reliability

I did some research on this, but wasn't able to find any substantial answers, so turning to StackOverflow.

How reliable is Amazon's S3 in terms of high-availability and reliability? I realize there are SLAs for it, but what about if a availability zone (AZ) or entire region in AWS goes down?

I checked up Amazon's docs on how S3 is set up. When you try to create a bucket, it says: "When creating a bucket, you can choose a Region to optimize for latency, minimize costs, or address regulatory requirements."

Amazon also says this ([source](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1904)): "Data stored in any given Amazon S3 bucket is replicated across multiple datacenters in a geographical region."

So it does look like S3 data is spread across multiple AZs, but within a region.

What if a region goes down (this has happened before)? Is S3 unavailable then? If so, S3 is not a reliable backup mechanism for restoration when a AWS region goes down, is it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

S3 offers "4 nines" of availability, or 99.99%.

For backups, you would be looking for Durability (chance that a stored object is lost).  On that account, S3 offers "11 9's", or 99.9999999%

Here's a blurb from the [S3 FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/):

> **Data Durability and Reliability**
>
> Amazon S3 provides a highly durable storage infrastructure designed
> for mission-critical and primary data storage. Objects are redundantly
> stored on multiple devices across multiple facilities in an Amazon S3
> Region. To help ensure durability, Amazon S3 PUT and COPY operations
> synchronously store your data across multiple facilities before
> returning SUCCESS. Once stored, Amazon S3 maintains the durability of
> your objects by quickly detecting and repairing any lost redundancy.
> Amazon S3 also regularly verifies the integrity of data stored using
> checksums. If corruption is detected, it is repaired using redundant
> data. In addition, Amazon S3 calculates checksums on all network
> traffic to detect corruption of data packets when storing or
> retrieving data.
>
> Amazon S3’s standard storage is:
>
> - Backed with the Amazon S3 Service Level Agreement.
> - Designed to provide 99.999999999% durability and 99.99% availability of objects over a given year.
> - Designed to sustain the concurrent loss of data in two facilities.

As for the Regions, you would have to implement a DIY replication strategy if you truly wanted cross-region failover.  An no, an entire region has not failed yet, but I guess there's a first for everything.

Here's some [more info](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#How_durable_is_Amazon_S3) on the topic:

> **Q: How durable is Amazon S3?**
>
> Amazon S3 is designed to provide
> 99.999999999% durability of objects over a given year. This durability level corresponds to an average annual expected loss of 0.000000001%
> of objects. For example, if you store 10,000 objects with Amazon S3,
> you can on average expect to incur a loss of a single object once
> every 10,000,000 years. In addition, Amazon S3 is designed to sustain
> the concurrent loss of data in two facilities.
>
> **Q: How is Amazon S3 designed to achieve 99.999999999% durability?**
>
> Amazon S3 redundantly stores your objects on multiple devices across
> multiple facilities in an Amazon S3 Region. The service is designed to
> sustain concurrent device failures by quickly detecting and repairing
> any lost redundancy. When processing a request to store data, the
> service will redundantly store your object across multiple facilities
> before returning SUCCESS. Amazon S3 also regularly verifies the
> integrity of your data using checksums.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the comprehensive answer. While an entire region hasn't failed, it has certainly been affected: http://aws.amazon.com/message/67457/. I didn't hear about S3 failing during that event earlier this year, but was wondering whether it could have.

Comment: AWS now supports [Cross-Region Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html) (as of [March 2015](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/)), so you don't have to DIY if you want your data to be replicated to a different region.

Comment: Is 99.99% availability measure by object, by bucket, or by the entire service ? Meaning: 99.99% per year means 52 minutes and 33 seconds of not be able to get to my data -- but is it for the entire account, bucket, or object?

Comment: Go To IBM CLoud object storage it is protected against region failure : https://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/bluemix/fr/cloud-object-storage